# How to match regular expression up to end of string?

Tags: regex, string, swift, match

I am trying to use regular expressions to check user input as they type. For example if I wanted to check against the string "Hello", and the user input was "H", "He", ..., "Hello" "Hello world" etc. it would be valid but "Hi", "H e" etc. would not.

I am currently using:

```
if let range = s.rangeOfString("^\\s*Hello", options: .RegularExpressionSearch){
    //Valid
}
```

But this does not accept "H", "He", etc. Is there a way to do this using regular expressions?

Comment: you need to add all the alternatives.

Comment: So something like "^\\s*H|He|Hel|Hell|Hello" you mean?

Comment: yep, like that. But use word boundaries also.

Comment: Maybe, This library helps you: https://github.com/pieceofsummer/WTReTextField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add all the alternatives like below.

```
^\\s*H(?:ello|el?l?)?\\b
```

Note that `?` repeats the previous token zero or 1 time. Don't consider the `?` present inside lookarounds `(?<=..)` , `(?=..)` or non-capturing group `(?:..)`. `|` called alternation operator. It will use the pattern on it's left side first. If this pattern finds a match then it won't touch the pattern which was present to it's right side. So `H(?:ello)\\b` matches `Hello` and `He` matches  `He`, since we made the `l` present in the 2nd pattern as optional. Likewise it goes on. `?` after the non-capturing group will make the whole group as optional one. So now we get a pattern like `^\\s*H\\b`, now this matches a single `H`.

Comment: That works great thank you! Could you explain a little about how the part in the bracket works?